# TypeError: send() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'interp' and 'cmd'

Tags: python

I got a `TypeError` while making a GUI program.

Here is the code:

```
import time, random
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master):
      Frame.__init__(self, master)
      self.grid()
      self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):
      self.lbl1=Label(self, text="Write your message:")
      self.lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

      self.entry=Entry(self)
      self.entry.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

      self.bttn=Button(self, text="Send", command=self.send)
      self.bttn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)


      def send(self):
          self.start=time.time()

          self.lbl2=Label(self, text="Sending...")
          self.lbl2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

          self.start.sleep(2)
          self.lbl2.destroy()


root=Tk()
root.title("Mail")
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: send() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'interp' and 'cmd'
```

I don't understand what this error means. Can someone tell me what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `send` function should have the same indentation as the `create_widgets` and the `__init__` function. In your `send` function, you have to replace `self.start.sleep(2)` with `time.sleep(2)`, a `time` object doesn't have any sleep function.

Here's the full code:

```
import time, random
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master):
      Frame.__init__(self, master)
      self.grid()
      self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):
      self.lbl1=Label(self, text="Write your message:")
      self.lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

      self.entry=Entry(self)
      self.entry.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

      self.bttn=Button(self, text="Send", command=self.send)
      self.bttn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)


   def send(self):
      # self.start=time.time()
      # I think you don't need that anymore...

      self.lbl2=Label(self, text="Sending...")
      self.lbl2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

      time.sleep(2)
      self.lbl2.destroy()


root=Tk()
root.title("Mail")
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And to add, since send is a function being overrided, it must have the same signature as the original: send(self, interp, cmd, *args).

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel: _"since send is a function being overrided, it must have the same signature as the original"_ That's not entirely true. It can any signature it wants, as long as it's only used with the new signature.

Answer (score 3):

Your `send` function is indented so it is defined inside of `create_widgets`. As a result, Python does not recognize it as a method of your `Application` class, and so `command=self.send` refers to the existing `send` method belonging to the parent `Frame` class.

De-indent your `send` method so it has the same level of indentation as all of your other class methods.

```
   def create_widgets(self):
       self.lbl1=Label(self, text="Write your message:")
       #etc

   def send(self):
       self.start=time.time()
       #etc
```

---

Alternatively, keep the indentation as it is, but change the argument list to `def send():`, move `def send` so it appears above the `self.bttn=Button(self, text="Send", command=self.send)` line, and remove the `self`s that are no longer needed.

```
   def create_widgets(self):
      def send():
          self.start=time.time()

          self.lbl2=Label(self, text="Sending...")
          self.lbl2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

          self.start.sleep(2)
          self.lbl2.destroy()

      self.lbl1=Label(self, text="Write your message:")
      self.lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

      self.entry=Entry(self)
      self.entry.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

      self.bttn=Button(self, text="Send", command=send)
      self.bttn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: It works, but now it gives me this error :File "C:/Python34/python 3.4/my_gmail2.pyw", line 27, in send
    self.start.sleep(2)   AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: That's because `time.time()` returns a floating point number, and floating point numbers don't have a `sleep` method. Are you trying to access the `sleep` method of the `time` module? Try doing `time.sleep(2)` instead. No `self` or assignment required.

Comment: Actually it's probably not advisable to use `sleep` at all in a Tkinter program, since it temporarily halts the mainloop and causes the application to become totally unresponsive. If you want an event to occur after a certain amount of time, consider using `root.after` instead.